# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
> TagsCheck(Library.MVVM.Model.Book)' method, and this method cannot be
> translated into a store expression

Насколько я понял, эта ошибка появляется потому что выражение в запросе не может преобразоваться в sql запрос. И я не могу понять как мне заменить мою функцию на запрос.

Сам запрос

```
BookList = db.Books.Include("Tags").Where(b => b.Name.Trim().Contains(BookSearch.Trim()) && TagsCheck(b)).ToList();
```

И функция

```
bool TagsCheck(Book book)
{
    using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        foreach (Tag tag in FilterTagList)
            if (!book.Tags.Contains(db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TagId == tag.TagId)))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

В самом запросе я пытаюсь получить список книг, в список тегов которых, входят теги из списка `FilterTagList`. Подскажите возможное решение.

Comment: Все просто и ровно так, как написано в тексте сообщения от ошибке. Пользовательская функция не может быть транслирована в SQL, поэтому надо выполнять ее не в бд, а в клиенте. Для этого сначала делайте ToList, а потом уже эту проверку: `.ToList().Where(TagsCheck).ToList()`

Comment: @АндрейNOP - не советуйте плохое. Жаль, нельзя комментариям минус ставить.

Comment: Ваш метод должен возвращать `Expression<Func<Book, bool>>`.

Comment: @Alexander, может и пример напишете, как приведённую функцию переделать? Я вот надеюсь, что первое условие в запросе отсеет много записей и на клиента не будет вытягиваться пол базы

Comment: Тут у ТС и без этого проблем хватает, хотя бы то, что эти две части в разных контекстах работают, причем для каждой книги контекст будет свой

Comment: Второй контекст не нужен, от него следует избавиться, конечно.

Comment: Если вы укажете **точную** версию вашей ORM: EF 6, EF Core - и приведёте описание ваших сущностей, то я, вероятно, дам вам ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы корректно описали ту часть кода, которую вы не показали здесь, касательно строения классов Book и Tag, а так-же BookSearch поля, заведены компараторы на подобии TagComparer, то должно быть достаточно:

```
class TagComparer : IEqualityComparer<Tag>
{
    public bool Equals(Tag t1, Tag t2)
    {
        if (t1 == null && t2 == null) return true;
        else if (t1 == null || t2 == null) return false;
        else if (t1.TagId == t2.TagId) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Tag tx)
    {
        return (tx?.TagId ?? 0).GetHashCode();
    }
}

BookList = db.Books
   .Include("Tags")
   .Where(b 
      => b.Name.Contains(BookSearch.Trim()) 
      && b.Tags.Any(a => FilterTagList.Contains(a, new TagComparer())))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Уверены, что это сработает?

Comment: @АндрейNOP просто на модели без бд - работает. Компараторы, насколько мне известно, в sql переводятся. Всё остальное - стандартно. Не вижу причин чтобы это не сработало.

Comment: Интересно, я попробовал выполнить запрос с компаратором: он не может быть транслирован в SQL. Именно из-за наличия компаратора. | Погуглил: нигде нет внятного ответа, можно ли использовать компараторы сущностей именно на стороне СУБД.

Comment: @Alexander, уверен, что нельзя. В компараторе мы можем написать что угодно и как это "что угодно" транслировать в SQL?

Comment: @АндрейNOP - я полностью согласен

Answer (score 0):

Метод `TagsCheck` должен возвращать `Expression<Func<Book, bool>>`, чтобы его можно было использовать в linq-запросах Entity Framework.

Насколько я понял, в этом методе проверяется, содержится ли хоть один тег, назначенный книге, в списке `FilterTagList`.

Этот код можно записать так:

```
Expression<Func<Book, bool>> TagsCheck()
{
    return book => book.Tags.Any(tag => FilterTagList.Contains(tag));
}
```

Использовать его следует так:

```
var books = db.Books.Include("Tags")
    .Where(b => b.Name.Trim().Contains(BookSearch.Trim()))
    .Where(TagsCheck())
    .ToList();
```

Обратите внимание, его **обязательно** нужно использовать так: `Where(TagsCheck())`. Потому что он возвращает `Expression`! Он **не** возвращает значение `bool`!

Его невозможно использовать вот так: `.Where(book => TagsCheck())`, потому что тогда он конвертируется в делегат.

Он возвращает выражение `book => book.Tags.Any(tag => FilterTagList.Contains(tag))` и именно оно будет подставлено в месте вызова.

И, соответственно, такой метод не получится использовать с логическим оператором `&&`. Отсюда следует отдельный вызов `Where`.

---

Метод не принимает параметр, потому что параметр `book` принимает `Expression` (выражение). Поэтому, чтобы не возникло соблазна всё-таки попытаться воткнуть какой-нибудь параметр, можно сделать свойство вместо метода:

```
Expression<Func<Book, bool>> TagsCheck =>
    book => book.Tags.Any(tag => FilterTagList.Contains(tag));
```

Его использование, естественно, будет без круглых скобочек:

```
.Where(TagsCheck)
```