# Написание обобщённой LINQ-фильтрации

Tags: c#, linq

Я хочу написать абстрактную фильтрацию по полям моделей.

```cs
public static class Filter
{
    public static List<IModelContext> FilterWith<IModelContext>(this DbSet<IModelContext> dbSet, string property, object compared) where IModelContext : class
    {            
        return dbSet.Where(x => x.IsFilter(property, compared)).ToList();
    }

    public static bool IsFilter<IModelContext>(this IModelContext model, string property, object compared)
    {
        return model?.GetType().GetProperty(property)?.GetValue(model, null)?.Equals(compared) ?? false;
    }
}
```

В тестовом консольном приложении я вызываю этот метод

```cs
bool filtered = ctx.Measure.First().IsFilter("Conditions", "value");
List<Measure> filteredList = ctx.Measure.FilterWith("Conditions", "value");
```

Метод `IsFilter` по одиночке работает, но вкупе с LINQ запросом отваливается с ошибкой. При вызове `FilterWith` выбрасывает в ошибку:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Measure>()
    .Where(m => m
        .IsFilter(
            property: __property_0, 
            compared: __compared_1))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."
```

Как только их не компоновал, миксовал сравнения в предикате:

- tostring equals

```cs
.GetValue(model, null).ToString().Equals(compared.ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ?? false;)
```

- ==

```cs
.GetValue(model, null) == compared
```

По всей видимости суть в неявных операциях во время одиночного сравнения которые LINQ не может принять, но не могу понять в чем именно.

Comment: Чтобы метод транслировался в SQL, он должен возвращать не `bool`, а `Expression<bool>`.

Comment: Метод [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-6.0) позволяет легко работать со свойствами сущностей. P. S. Не уверен, что он работает со всеми СУБД. Укажите, какую именно вы используете.

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1444479/184217), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1437904/184217), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1301497/184217), [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1003995/184217), [5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1401816/184217) - можете ознакомиться с ответами по теме.

Answer (score 0):

> ## Явное вычисление на стороне клиента
>
> ### В некоторых случаях, например, в указанных ниже, может потребоваться явное принудительное вычисление на стороне клиента.
>
> Объем данных мал, поэтому вычисление в клиенте не приводит к значительному снижению производительности.
> Используемый оператор LINQ не преобразуется на стороне сервера.

гласит документация. Стоило лишь открыть ссылку из ошибки.
solution:

```cs
return dbSet
    .AsEnumerable() // <-- added
    .Where(x => x.IsFilter(property, compared));
```